# Why do we start from $KLD(q(z) || p(z|x))$ in ELBO derivation?

Tags: posterior, variational-bayes

Of the several ways to derive the evidence lower bound (such as using Jensen’s inequality), a version often used is the derivation from $KLD(q(z) || p(z|x))$.

The following image illustrates the derivation process (screenshotted from [here](https://mpatacchiola.github.io/blog/2021/01/25/intro-variational-inference.html)):
[image]

While I do understand how the math works out, I do not have an argument for using $KLD(q(z) || p(z|x))$ as a starting point. Why $KLD(q(z) || p(z|x))$, and not $KLD(q(z) || p(z))$ or $KLD(q(z|x) || p(z|x))$?

If someone asks me the motivation of wanting to calculate $KLD(q(z) || p(z|x))$ (as opposed to KLD between other distributions, as listed above), what can I tell them?

Comment: I don’t think this is a natural direction to go at all. I would start from the (intractable) marginal probability of $x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $q(\mathbf{z})$ chosen to be the posterior distribution in the EM algorithm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533430/why-is-q-mathbfz-chosen-to-be-the-posterior-distribution-in-the-em-algorit)

Answer (score 1):

For Variational Bayes, the aim is to **approximate the intractable posterior distribution $p(z \mid x)$ with a variational approximation $q(z)$ which is an easy, parametric distribution to perform posterior inference**. That is why we want to optimize the KLD between $q(z)$ and $p(z|x)$. You can review [Variational Inference: A Review for Statisticians](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00670) section 2.2.

As in your derivations, it's most of the time impossible to directly optimize this KLD due to the $\log p(x)$ being intractable. This intractability because evidence integral is unavailable in closed form or requires exponential time to compute. Assuming that $p(x,z) = p(z) p(x \mid z)$, an important assumption in VI, you minimize the KLD between

TL;DR, VI tries to find a $q(z)$ closest to the $p(z \mid x)$ via minimizing the KL divergence between them. **That's the original problem**. Your derivations are showing the equivalent problem which is required due to the evidence term.

For more technical depth, it's possible to define VI over priors or even function spaces. [Doubly Semi-Implicit Variational Inference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02789) can be good reading for defining VI over both posterior and prior.