# EM equality constraint using Jensen's Inequality

Tags: self-study, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to derive the ELBO as per [CS229 Page 144, Eq 11.8](https://cs229.stanford.edu/lectures-spring2022/main_notes.pdf).

For E-step, the LHS and RHS must be equal:
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\left[ \frac{p(x, z; \theta)}{Q(z)}\right]\right) \geq \mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\left[f\left( \frac{p(x, z; \theta)}{Q(z)}\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$

The value must be a constant random variable for equality to hold:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{p(x, z; \theta)}{Q(z)} = c
\end{align}
$$

This can be accomplished by choosing $Q(z) \propto p(x, z; \theta)$. Also, $\sum_z Q(z) = 1$.

**Part that is not clear:**
$$
\begin{align}
Q(z) = \frac{p(x, z; \theta)}{\sum_z p(x, z; \theta)}
\end{align}
$$
I'm aware of the simplification that *follows* this equation. But how did they arrive at this? Which property am I missing?

Comment: Maybe I don't properly understand your question: You look for a function that differs from $p$ only by a factor and that is also normalized. So just normalize it, i.e. divide by the sum of all values. You can check that now both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I get that the denominator is independent of $z$ after marginalization, and the whole fraction reduces to $p(z|x)$. My question is why that exact term in the denominator and nothing else? Most derivations directly assume $Q(z)=p(z|x)$, which is in fact derived from the equation above.

Comment: My question is a duplicate. Found the solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533430/why-is-q-mathbfz-chosen-to-be-the-posterior-distribution-in-the-em-algorit?rq=1)